# Create a new table from existing table with multiple custom columns

Tags: mysql

I have searched and searched for the answer to this but I cant find nothing.

At the moment this is my current query

```
  create TABLE VAR_PEAK
    as SELECT a.ID_NO, a.CODE,
    a.VAR1 as PKEI_1,
    a.VAR2 as PKEI_2,
    a.VAR3 as PKEI_3,
    b.VAR1 as PKE_1,
    b.VAR2 as PKE_2,
    b.VAR3 as PKE_3,
    c.VAR1 as PKW_1,
    c.VAR2 as PKW_2,
    c.VAR3 as PKW_3,
    d.VAR4 as PKWE_1,
    d.VAR4 as PKWE_2,
    d.VAR4 as PKWE_3
    from LIVE_VARAN a INNER JOIN LIVE_VARAN b ON a.ID_NO=b.ID_NO 
    INNER JOIN LIVE_VARAN c ON a.ID_NO=c.ID_NO
    INNER JOIN LIVE_VARAN d ON a.ID_NO=d.ID_NO

    WHERE a.VARIABLE = 'PKEI' AND a.POS = 'DES' AND b.VARIABLE = 'PKE' AND b.POS = 'DES' 
    AND c.VARIABLE = 'PKW' AND c.POS = 'DES' AND d.VARIABLE = 'PKWE' AND d.POS = 'DES'
```

This current query just does not run, it just loads and loads forever.

The Data is like this

```
ID_NO  VARIABLE  POS   VAR1   VAR2  VAR3
D55     PKEI     MES   4      5     9
D24     PKEI     MES   4      5     5
D78     PKE      MES   4      3     9
D45     PKE      MES   4      5     9
D54     PKWE     MES   21     5     9
D45     PKWE     MES   4      54    9
D55     PKW      MES   9      8     4
D54     PKEI     MES   1      1     4
D55     INT      CLE   100    100   124
```

The new table I'm trying to create would have the new column headers like this

```
ID_NO  CODE  PKEI_1 PKEI_2 PKEI_3 PKE_1 PKE_2 PKE_3 PKW_1 PKW_2 PKW_3 PKWE_1 PKWE_2 PKWE_3
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong in the query?

Comment: Why are you joining the same table multiple times? I don't see any need for that.

Answer (score 0):

#### Your JOIN is incorrect:

You are joining on the same ID: `a.ID_NO=b.ID_NO`, `a.ID_NO=c.ID_NO`, `a.ID_NO=d.ID_NO` and
there is only one `VARIABLE` field for each record,but you are trying to join rows from a, b, c, d where `a.VARIABLE = 'PKEI'` AND `b.VARIABLE = 'PKE'` AND `c.VARIABLE = 'PKW'` AND `d.VARIABLE = 'PKWE'`. How is it possible?

You will need to change `=` to `<>`

`a.ID_NO <> b.ID_NO`, `a.ID_NO <> c.ID_NO`, `a.ID_NO <> d.ID_NO`

#### Modified SQL

```
CREATE TABLE VAR_PEAK AS
SELECT a.ID_NO,
       a.CODE,
       a.VAR1 AS PKEI_1,
       a.VAR2 AS PKEI_2,
       a.VAR3 AS PKEI_3,
       b.VAR1 AS PKE_1,
       b.VAR2 AS PKE_2,
       b.VAR3 AS PKE_3,
       c.VAR1 AS PKW_1,
       c.VAR2 AS PKW_2,
       c.VAR3 AS PKW_3,
       d.VAR4 AS PKWE_1,
       d.VAR4 AS PKWE_2,
       d.VAR4 AS PKWE_3
FROM LIVE_VARAN a
INNER JOIN LIVE_VARAN b ON a.ID_NO<>b.ID_NO
INNER JOIN LIVE_VARAN c ON a.ID_NO<>c.ID_NO
INNER JOIN LIVE_VARAN d ON a.ID_NO<>d.ID_NO
WHERE a.VARIABLE = 'PKEI'
  AND a.POS = 'DES'
  AND b.VARIABLE = 'PKE'
  AND b.POS = 'DES'
  AND c.VARIABLE = 'PKW'
  AND c.POS = 'DES'
  AND d.VARIABLE = 'PKWE'
  AND d.POS = 'DES';
```

Comment: this is running but taking a long time, I will leave it to keep running for 5 minutes and let you know if it's worked

Comment: @Engl12, to me looks like you don't have any index on this table. Make sure to have index on `VARIABLE | POS | ID_NO` columns.

Comment: @Engl12, How many rows are in the Table? Always limit your initial test to just a few rows of the source table (say, something like 100) and see the results are meaningful. Otherwise, you would be wasting your time waiting for results that you don't want.

Comment: @kums around 5 million rows, your query brought my server down, it created a table containing 70 million rows

Comment: Is that in a production server? I really can't understand why you would apply something without testing them first in an isolated data set. Sad!